# C# Unity Dictionary or else

Tags: c#, dictionary, unity-game-engine

I'am making a game with unity where I will use Oxford 5000 english words and the translations in my native language and create a game focused on teaching english words to non native speakers.

I'am planning on using 2 Dictionaries each containing 5k words every word will have an ID which match the ID of their translation, Is this a correct approach? Is it ok to have 5k data in a single Dictionary?

2 Huge Dictionaries is it okay?

Comment: The most efficient way would probably be to store it in a db with id, value, translated value

Comment: You might want to consider something like MasterMemory (https://github.com/Cysharp/MasterMemory) which is a very fast, very efficient, in-memory database.

Comment: "have 5k data in a single Dictionary?" and "2 Huge Dictionaries is it okay" statements feel completely unrelated. Could you please clarify which one is actually correct? (The question is largely opinion based as you are expected to perform measurements yourself for your specific case and ask specific question if you don't understand results)

Answer (score 2):

It depends what you mean by "okay".

If you're asking if that will crash the program, no, it won't.  It will work.

But at the very least, I'd recommend keeping both words in a custom struct/class so you're not duplicating the keys in two dictionaries needlessly.

As with most programming, though, the best answer is to try it out.  And if it doesn't work, fix it.